# In my android app.i used SOAP webservices, now issue related to timeout

Tags: android, web-services, soap, timeout

This is my Code of internet checking

```
 public String isConnectingToInternet()
     {
         ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         if (connectivity != null)
         {
             NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
             if (info != null)
             for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
             {
                 if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                     // return true;
                    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)_context.getSystemService(_context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                        try
                        {
                            URL url = new URL("http://google.com");   // Change to "http://google.com" for www  test.
                            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            urlc.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000000);          // 10 s.
                            urlc.connect();
                            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200||urlc.getResponseCode() == 302) {        // 200 = "OK" code (http connection is fine).
                               // Log.wtf("Connection", "Success !");
                                return "-2";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return "-3";  // "Oops ! \n \n server is currently down.Please try again.";
                            }
                        }
                        catch (MalformedURLException e1)
                        {
                            return "-3";  //"Oops ! \n \n server is currently down.Please try again.";
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                            Log.d("", ""+e);

                            return "-3";  //"Oops ! \n \n server is currently down.Please try again.";
                        }
                    }
                    return "-3";  //"Oops ! \n \n server is currently down.Please try again.";

                  }
             }
         }
         return "-4";  //"Error Coneectiong. \n Please make sure you have an Internet connection and try again.";
     }
```

This is my code for call weservice

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

envelope.dotNet = true;
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

try {
    ss = null;
    ss = connectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet();
                            if (ss.equals("-2"))
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(USER_DETAILS_SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
        uDetailsResponse = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        System.out.println("InonPre -------------output "+ uDetailsResponse);
    }
    else
    {
        return "false";
    }
```

Comment: Increase the timeout duration. This happens if you are on lower internet connectivity bandwidth and may take more that normal time. So increase time out to 2 mins for instance

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to solve that issue? Maybe one could make the timeout adaptive to the bandwith.